# Propagating HTTP header into all sub-sequent calls

Tags: java, spring, http-headers

Our Java Spring application receives header information in request calls, such as Authorization information. What would be the best way in Spring to ensure that the header information is passed on in all sub-sequent outward http calls?

Comment: The only thing that can remove a header is a custom filter. Don't do that and you are good to go. I realy don't understand the problem here.

Comment: How are you making the outward bound calls?

Comment: Stephen C: I call a Rest consumer, implemented using RestTemplate. The header of the http request that I received, should be appended to the RestTemplate call.